# Android/Java HttpURLConnection: difference between setUseCaches() and setDefaultUseCaches()

Tags: java, android, caching, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I would like to know the difference between the HttpUrlConnection [setUseCaches(boolean newValue)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setUseCaches(boolean)) and [setDefaultUseCaches(boolean newValue)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDefaultUseCaches(boolean))

It appears that they do the same thing, despite getting/setting different member values.

I checked the source code files [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/jb-release/luni/src/main/java/java/net/URLConnection.java) and [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/jb-release/luni/src/main/java/java/net/HttpURLConnection.java) and can't find the scenario where we need to set the values for both.

can anyone tell the a real scenario that shows the distinction between the two methods?

Answer (score 0):

The default version will set the default value for `useCaches` for any new `UrlConnection` created (the field is `static`).

So for any new `UrlConnection`, the `useCaches` flag will be set to whatever value your last call to `setDefaultUseCaches` contained.

A scenario where this is useful is where your application only uses `setUseCaches` when absolutely needed, while all other connections created can use a globally configured default value.  `setDefaultUseCaches` should therefore probably only be used during startup, and never during normal use of your application.